# R: rCharts and Shiny, charts won't show up when I run it

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rcharts

This seems like an ongoing question. I saw this posted a few times, I tried all the different solutions people offered. But nothing works for me.
My chart won't show up when I run it :(

Here is my ui.R

```
## ui.R
require('rCharts')
require('shiny')
require("quantmod")
require("TTR")
require("stringr")
require('lubridate')
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('test'),
  sidebarPanel(p('test')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput('graph',lib='polycharts')
  )
))
```

and here is my server.R

```
#Dependencies
require('rCharts')
require('shiny')
require("quantmod")
require("TTR")
require("stringr")
require('lubridate')

#functions
SYM<-function (x,loc='yahoo') {
  getSymbols(x,src=loc)
  return(get(x))}

data.setup<-function(data,loc='yahoo',start.date=Sys.Date()-months(1),
                     end.date=Sys.Date()) {
  getSymbols(data,src=loc)
  x<-as.data.frame(window(SYM(data,loc=loc),
                          start=as.character(start.date),
                          end=as.character(end.date)))
  x$dates<-row.names(x)
  return(return(x)) 
}

## server.r
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$graph <- renderChart2({
    a<-data.setup('AAPL')  
    m1 <- mPlot(x = 'dates', y = c("AAPL.High", "AAPL.Low"), type = "Line", data = a)
    m1$set(dom = 'graph')
    return(m1)
  })
})
```

*My main issue is that I can't understand how does the showOutput function works.
What is the lib in showOutput referring to? I can't find any guide that explains that.
I am still a newbie when it comes to environments in R. A answer aimed at that is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using `renderChart2`, remove the line where you set `m1$set(dom = 'graph')`. That line is needed only with `renderChart`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: no that did not work, same result. As in... no plot

Comment: Ah okay. You are using `mPlot`, which corresponds to the library `morrisjs`. You need to use `showOutput('graph', 'morris')`.

Comment: That worked!
Is there anywhere I can lookup what values of lib work when?
Or learn the logic for it?

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts) here has examples of most of the libraries. By convention, `showOutput` always uses all lowercase name of the library. You can also know the library generating the plot by typing `m1$lib`.

Comment: Posting comment as answer so that u can close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `showOutput` line needs to use `lib = "morris"` since the OP is using `mPlot`. For a full list of libraries, you can see the [README](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts). Alternately, you can also get the name of the library by typing `m1$lib`.

Comment: dr, using this example: `nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = 'multiBarChart')` I get no output, no error, whatsoever. I'm trying to do the same for **discreteBarChart**

Answer (score 2):

This works as mentioned in the comments. I just add it here so it's easier to find for others.

```
require('rCharts')
require('shiny')
require("quantmod")
require("TTR")
require("stringr")
require('lubridate')
options(RCHART_LIB = 'morris')

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('test'),
  sidebarPanel(p('test')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput('graph',lib='morris')
  )
))

#Dependencies
require('rCharts')
require('shiny')
require("quantmod")
require("TTR")
require("stringr")
require('lubridate')

#functions
SYM<-function (x,loc='yahoo') {
  getSymbols(x,src=loc)
  return(get(x))}

data.setup<-function(data,loc='yahoo',start.date=Sys.Date()-months(1),
                     end.date=Sys.Date()) {
  getSymbols(data,src=loc)
  x<-as.data.frame(window(SYM(data,loc=loc),
                          start=as.character(start.date),
                          end=as.character(end.date)))
  x$dates<-row.names(x)
  return(return(x))
}

## server.r
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$graph <- renderChart2({
    a<-data.setup('AAPL')
    m1 <- mPlot(x = 'dates', y = c("AAPL.High", "AAPL.Low"), type = "Line", data = a)
    return(m1)
  })
})
```