# rCharts with Shiny no charts show out

Tags: rcharts, shiny

I try to write a simple shinyapps at [***customer-service-handbook-TEST1***](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/englianhu/customer-service-handbook-TEST1/) but there has no any graph display. I use `runApp('TEST', display.mode='showcase')` to make the codes visible on the apps.

What I want in the output in different tabPanels are similar with below links :

- tabPanel 1 : [dTable fancy DataTable](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?6033141#.VxUCdvl96Um)
- tabPanel 2 : [nPlot MultiBarChart](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?5457195#.VxUCf_l96Um)
- tabPanel 3 : [Line/Area Chart in Example 07](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_rickshaw_gettingstarted/index.html)

Related posts which have no output when applied rCharts and Shiny:

- [R: rCharts and Shiny, charts won't show up when I run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378491/r-rcharts-and-shiny-charts-wont-show-up-when-i-run-it)
- [Shiny rcharts multiple chart output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895321/shiny-rcharts-multiple-chart-output)
- [rCharts with shiny, no rescaling of bars after hide/unhide with Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388316/rcharts-with-shiny-no-rescaling-of-bars-after-hide-unhide-with-highcharts)

Comment: How about showing your code? Now it is really hard to tell. Maybe you could write [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of one your tabs.

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen Kindly refer to [Natural-Language-Analysis](https://github.com/englianhu/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/tree/master/Natural-Language-Analysis) as the `display.mode='showcase'` doesn't work.